# Alamofire 2.0 Compiler Issues - Swift 2 / Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, swift2, alamofire

I'm having trouble converting my project to Xcode 7 Beta related to the Alamofire 2.0 as shown on the screenshot below. Even created a test project with the following podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```

I also reinstalled cocoapods. Still same problem. Anyone have some idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to the official Xcode 7.0 GM release. The Xcode 7 betas are no longer working with the Alamofire 2.x releases. They only worked with the betas. To run Alamofire 2.0.2, you need to be using Xcode 7 (7A220).